# Xubuntu20.04 LTS desktop keyboard and mouse stop working randomly AFTER suspend

Tags: keyboard, mouse, 20.04, xfce

On my desktop computer (recently changed to Xubuntu and kept up-to-date), the keyboard and mouse stop working apparently only after resuming from suspend and a delay of several minutes.   The mouse pointer continues to move, but no mouse clicks have any effect.  W/o the keyboard working, I cannot open terminals/consoles.

I enabled sshd so that I can log into the frozen GUI system, and top shows a 'normal' system (e.g., very low CPU use, low memory use, no swapping, etc.).  Based on some research, I set /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend to -1 (i.e., disabled autosuspend on every USB port), but that did not help matters.

No particular program seems to trigger the issue ... often I'm in google-chrome because that's how I mostly use the system, but I can be in PyCharm, an image viewer, or anything else I might happen to be using.

Except for the random GUI freezing, I have not seen any other issues with peripherals (including the scanner, monitors, mouse, keyboard, etc).
Also, this same hardware ran for several years under Windows 10
w/o any problems in this arena; so the hardware is fine.

Here is some system info:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"

$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 045e:00dd Microsoft Corp. Comfort Curve Keyboard 2000 V1.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 062a:4102 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. 2.4G Wireless Mouse
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04a9:190f Canon, Inc. CanoScan LiDE 220
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f1)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z170 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde PRO / Venus LE / Tropo PRO-L [Radeon HD 8830M / R7 250 / R7 M465X] (rev 87)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland/Hainan/Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7000 Series]
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: ADATA Technology Co., Ltd. XPG SX8200 Pro PCIe Gen3x4 M.2 2280 Solid State Drive (rev 03)
04:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller


$ cat /proc/meminfo | head -3
MemTotal:       32774636 kB
MemFree:        27201232 kB
MemAvailable:   28870780 kB
```

So, there is lots of memory ... much more than I could exhaust in practice.
top always show zero used swap.  I have complicated monitor situation, four monitors
with two off the onboard Intel HD Graphics 530 and two from the add-on AMD Radeon R7 250 card.

Any suggestions on how to best isolate the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody offered any suggestions and I figured it was a problem with my oddball setup (using four monitors with two graphics controllers of different brands) ... even though it worked fine for years using Windows 10. I replaced the two graphics controllers with just one, a Sapphire Radeon RX 580 which supports up to 5 monitors.

The system comes up noticeably cleaner (i.e., all four monitors almost at once) and the freeze after resumption of suspend has NOT been seen after many tries that would have caused many freezes previously.

So, I would not call this a "solution", but it sure seems to be a "workaround".